# How to define a site with max 1200 pixel?

Tags: html, css

What does it mean when somebody says that the html site is max 1200 pixel?
How can i define it in html or css so that the site does not go more than 1200 pixel width?

Comment: `max-width:1200px;` in css

Comment: and you found nothing when doing a google search ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this term would refer to the actual content of the body of the website.

The key item in the code below is `max-width:1200px;`

This will fix the width of the entire sites content to never grow larger than the specified size.

```css
div.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width:1200px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

header,
footer {
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  float: left;
  max-width: 160px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

article {
  margin-left: 170px;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <header>
    <h1>City Gallery</h1>
  </header>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tokyo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <article>
    <h1>London</h1>
    <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
    <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
  </article>

  <footer>Copyright &copy; W3Schools.com</footer>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this on your css script

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
             max-width: 1200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1):

on your body css just add

```
.body{ max-height: 'your max px or %'; 
 max-width:'your max px or %';}
```

maybe search on google at first , just a suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set your main container to:

```
.container{
max-width: 1200px;
width:100%;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

`max-width` will set a maximum width of 1200px, `width: 100%` will set the content inside `.container` to fill the maximum space of their container (1200px in this case), and `margin: 0 auto` will center `.container` in the window for those windows which are bigger than 1200px.